# 401 Unauthorised error -- css & js files in https site

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, 401

I have a SharePoint 2013 web application with only one zone in AAM(default configured with https).

The application works fine but I see 410 errors for a few css & js files. These files are under master page folder. They have been published. the error appears even for farm admin user.

Would somebody help me solve the 401 Unauthorized error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all users have read permission to the master page folder. Usually the root site visitor group (read only) is added to this folder, so I guess you've forgotten to add `All Users (Windows)` to the visitor group.